Implementing custom watermark over a video player (better_player)widget
i'm trying to implement a custom watermark over a  video player (better_player) widget, it works just fine when the video is NOT in full screen i.e THE PHONE IS IN PORTRAIT MODE (IMAGE below):

but the problem is when i enter full-screen mode, flutter widget inspector shows that the watermark is still in place ,but it's not shown on screen (image below):
this is my code:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    final provider = Provider.of<SeriesVideoProvider>(context);
    final seriesVideo = provider.seriesVideo;
  
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: seriesVideo == null
          ? kProgressIndicator
          : _betterPlayerController != null
              ? Center(
                  child: Stack(children: [
                    AspectRatio(
                      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                      child: BetterPlayer(controller: _betterPlayerController!),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      top: 0,
                      left: 0,
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.7),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        child: Text(
                          'My WaterMark',
                          style: GoogleFonts.cairo(
                            fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 23,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                )

         : kProgressIndicator,

    );
  }

